# Laya Yoga: Upanishad References

Tags: upanishads, yoga, tantra, reference-request

Laya Yoga - references in Upanishads.

I've heard that the methods of creation of mantras (beeja mantras specifically) follow from laya yoga where they use petals of certain chakras (or nadis) OR hear the internal sounds from the body in order to form syllable which is used to replicate a particular form of samadhi later on.

My question is far from Tantra, but particularly from Upanishads only - of references where beeja mantras like - *om* are heard from inside (internal sounds).
One good reference is - Nada Bindu Upanishad which covers internal sounds extensively, but not om sound. I wish to find a *Upanishad* that covers this particular case.

---

Other Upanishads such as *Yoga Sikha Upanishad* do cover laya yoga, but it isn't very intensive or informative either.

Thank You.

---

Edit 1: I looked upon panchabindu upanishad, I don't find anything very meaningful regarding laya yoga here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dhyana-Bindu Upanishad.:

> 97-102. The letter ‘Ha’ is the Bija of Akasa, is of Samana and is of the colour of crystal. Prana stays in the heart, navel, nose, ear, foot, finger and other places, travels through the seventy-two thousand Nadis, stays in the twenty-eight Crores of hair-pores and is yet the same everywhere. It is that which is called Jiva. One should perform the three, expiration, etc., with a firm will and great control; and drawing in everything (with the breath) in slow degrees, he should bind Prana and Apana in the cave of the lotus of the heart and utter Pranava, having contracted his throat and the genital organ. From the Muladhara (to the head) is the Susumna resembling the shining thread of the lotus. **The Amurtam Nada is located in the Vinadanda (spinal column); Like (abstract sound) is heard in the middle of conch sound, etc.**

I hope this helps. Prd..

Comment: This is a very good answer referencing a very prominent non-sectarian Upanishad. Thank you so much for adding your wisdom here, I've accepted the answer too. :)

Comment: You are most Welcome. ..

Answer (score 2):

- Nada Bindu Upanishad:

> 4. The Yogin’s Chitta having given up fame or disgrace is in Samadhi above the three states.
> 5. Being freed from the waking and the sleeping states, he attains to his true state.
> 6. When the (spiritual) sight becomes fixed without any object to be seen, when the Vayu (Prana) becomes still without any effort, and when
>    the Chitta becomes firm without any support, he becomes of the form of
>    the internal sound of Brahma-Pranava.

Src: [https://www.vedarahasya.net/nadabind.htm#:~:text=54.%20The%20Yogin%E2%80%99s,of%20Brahma%2DPranava](https://www.vedarahasya.net/nadabind.htm#:%7E:text=54.%20The%20Yogin%E2%80%99s,of%20Brahma%2DPranava).

The way of using Laya Yoga to recover the sound of beeja mantra Om (or Pranava) is also one of the ways to get enlightenment. This is evident from the last line: *he becomes the form of the internal sound of Brahma-Pranava* (Aum).

The method to listening the internal sound (that is everywhere internally as well as externally in the universe, Om [Mandukya Upanishad]), is written in the Upanishad.

This serves as an example to the question of internally recovering the beeja mantras for meditation.